# SetFocus not working on Activity's EditText with Hardware Keyboard when there is an RecyclerView with Buttons

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a Kotlin shopping cart activity with an EditText where users scan in barcodes using a bluetooth barcode scanner (acting as a hardware keyboard).  When the user scans in an item, the item is added to a RecyclerView shopping cart where they can adjust the quantity (with buttons on the CardView row).

When the activity first starts the focus is in the EditText and the soft keyboard isn't present.  However when the user scans a barcode (the CR is added by the bluetooth barcode scanner) I can't get the focus to automatically go back to the EditText so the user can scan the next barcode.  The setfocus on the edittext just doesn't seem to work.  The focus is actually set to one of the buttons in the RecyclerView CardView Row.

The user can touch in the EditText to set the focus (and bring up the soft keyboard).  But I don't want the user to have to do that in between each scan.

I've unsuccessfully played around with SetFocus and SetOnFocusChangeListener but haven't been able to get anything to work.  I've had this SetFocus working in the past when the CardView didn't have any clickable items in it.  But seemingly adding a CardView with buttons and/or clickable TextViews breaks the SetFocus on the Activity's EditText.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You can see this same problem by using the PC keyboard when running the Android Emulator.  When using the PC keyboard I can type in the first item, but I can't get the focus to return to the item prompt - the focus is on one of the recyclerview views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a difference in the way focus works when checking for the Enter key being pressed.  When I used KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, I just couldn't get the focus to work no matter what I tried.  When I used KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, then the focus worked just as I expected it to.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...
        // when using bar code scanner (or PC Keyboard when using Android Emulator), process barcode at Enter on end of barcode scan
        test_editTextSearch.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                searchItems()
                return@OnKeyListener true
            }
            false
        })
}

    fun searchItems() {
        cartItemsList.add(test_editTextSearch.text.toString())
        rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() //Update Screen
        test_editTextSearch.setText("")
        test_editTextSearch.requestFocus()
    }
```